# Is it possible add any class or id of a tag to another tag without editing html file?

Tags: html, editing

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://expandingant.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/messageusnormal.jpg" alt="messageusnormal" class="ncf_trigger_element" style="cursor: pointer; display:none\9; ">
</p>
```

I want to use class `ncf_trigger_element` (`ncf_trigger_element` used in the `img` tag) in the `p` tag without editing the HTML file and it would work same as does in `img` tag. How can I do this?

Comment: Need more information, what actually you want to do. Please share some code/background of problem.

Comment: you can add css rule like `img.ncf_trigger_element` this may work

Comment: Actually I want to use the class"ncf_trigger_element" (used in ing tag) in p tag by editing css file and not using javascripts. Is it possible ?. the class expands a message box and I want it in p tag as same as does in img tag

Comment: too much guesswork needed. provide more details and code or break your problem into smaller parts and separate Questions

Comment: <p style="text-align: center;">
 <img src="http://expandingant.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/messageusnormal.jpg" alt="messageusnormal" class="ncf_trigger_element" style="cursor: pointer; display:none\9; " "="">
</p>  

This is my code and I want the class work in p tag without editing html file.I want to edit css file.

Comment: I want the solutions immediately .Please help me out as soon as possible.

Comment: i still dont know how this thing works and/or what you want to achieve. im only seeing plain markup, nothing alive. please see the how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you can't understand this and edit your question your chances getting help are not the best

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible add any class or id of a tag to another tag without editing html file?"

Almost yes(?) With javascript you can search and find all the elements you want, and add a class to them, without editing *html DOM* (you'll have to edit HTML *file* to add javascript - that's why i say "Almost yes(?)").

```
var my_elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (i = 0; i < my_elements.length; i++)
{
    my_elements[i].className = my_elements[i].className + " the_class_you_want_to_add";
}

for (i = 0; i < my_elements.length; i++)
{
    alert(my_elements[i].className);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLra63ky/

"and it would work same as does in img tag." You provide us no information on how the img tag works already for you.

Comment: Actually I want to use the class"ncf_trigger_element" (used in ing tag) in p tag by editing css file and not using javascripts. Is it possible ?. the class expands a message box and I want it in p tag as same as does in img tag

Comment: I want the solutions immediately .Please help me out as soon as possible.